# How to set up home path in webpack

Tags: webpack, configuration, path

I have a `React` project and I am using `webpack` to generate a bundle.

In my components, I reference other components using relative paths.

For example, if I have a structure like this, this is how my imports would look:

```
- src
   - actions
   - components
         - my_component
```

If I wanted to import a `action` in `my_component`, I would do this.

`import {my_action} from ../actions`

I am telling my component `go up one level, go into actions and pick up my_action from there`.

I know it is possible to do imports like this:

`import {my_action} from @/actions`

I want to say `from the root directory, go into actions and pick up my_action from there`.

My question is, how do I make `@` usable as project root in my project?

Thanks!

---

**Edit 1**

I started my app with `create-react-app` and ejected. I retained the structure though, so I have something like this:

```
- frontend
    - config
        - webpack.config.dev
        - webpack.config.prod
    - src
        - actions
        - my_components
```

Because of this structure, I added this in both `webpack.config` files.

```
let up = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');
let src_path = path.resolve(up, 'src');
```

I logged `src_path` and it looked correct to my, namely, it was something like this.

```
/path/to/my/project/frontend/src
```

I had to do it like this because simply doing `path.resolve(__dirname, "src")` ended up with `/path/to/my/project/frontend/config/src`, which is obviously incorrect.

Even though I export `context: src_path`, I still get this error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '~/actions' in '/path/to/my/project/frontend/src/my_components'
```

Am I perhaps doing something wrong with my `path.resolve`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best practice to put your webpack.config.js file in frontend directory and you shouldn't do this:

`let up = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');
 let src_path = path.resolve(up, 'src');`

Just do this:

`let src_path = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');`

For using short file or module name you should define aliases using `resolve.alias` in webpack.config.js.

For example:

`resolve: {
    alias: {
      Actions: './actions',
//OR
      ActionFirst: './actions/action-first',
    },`

And You can use this alias:

`import ActionFirst from 'Actions/action-first';
//OR
 import ActionFirst from 'ActionFirst';`

Answer (score 0):

With React and ES6 you can even do the following:

```
import {my_action} from '~actions';
```

To achieve that is in your `webpack.config.js` file, by setting `context` as one of the exported properties:

```
context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
```

You can read more here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/

Comment: I see what you mean, I tried that, but it doesn't seem to work. I will make a edit with what I did.